# Does this question fits in on AskUbuntu?

Tags: support

The question - [How to automatically restart Tomcat7 on Ubuntu on system reboots [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13542030/932307) was closed as off-topic by community on SO. I flagged the question for moderator attention requesting it to be shifted to AskUbuntu.
The moderator declined the request and left the comment `I'm not sure its OT over there. Can you ask on their meta?`

I tried but could not find the meaning of OT? Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OT means Off-topic. From what I can tell it's On-topic for Ask Ubuntu. However, instead of requesting a migration (which doesn't get you much since there are no comments or answers) why not just re-post the question here? It'd be faster than waiting for a moderator to actually migrate it.

Comment: I don't know if that will be a acceptable. Once my SF account was closed for deleting my own questions. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157036/187200

Comment: Unless you delete a bunch of questions, I think you'll be OKay, but it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks Marco. I really like askubuntu.com everyone is so helping even to a new user like me.